# Custom input field border behavior when trying to include password eye

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a custom input field with a text input and a button with an eye icon to show/hide the password text.

Now, I know that simply create an input field and absolutely position the eye button but the problem with that is that on certain browsers, the Lastpass extension or Safari keychain will insert their respective icons thus overlapping the eye icon which I always want to be visible and clickable. As an example, this is bad:

[image]

Therefore, this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I am trying something like this:

```
<div className="input-wrapper">
    <input className="password-input" type="password" />
    <button className="password-eye">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.password-input {
    border: none;
    width: calc(100% - 32px);
    height: 40px;
}

.password-eye:extend(.icon-password-eye all) {
    background: white;
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

.icon-password-eye::before {
    content: '\e618';
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that because I want the whole wrapper to behave as if it were an input component, when the user selects the input field, only the actual input part is selected. In addition, if the password validation errors out, only input field is shown to be red while I want the entire portion to be red.

This is what is happening:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more  boilerplate code, *icon library*. What i see in you code now, only input field and  small *dot* or *circle*.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is changing the border CSS of the input-wrapper class.
and not the input

you need to change the code that changing the input css to change the input-wrapper css.

if you need help in that , please give the full code.